# Are there infinitely many prime p, such that p=1296k^2+36k+7?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

I encountered a number theory problem when doing my research:

1.I want to know whether or not there are infinitely many primes $p$ satistying $gcd(\frac{p-1}{6},6)=1$, such that $6$ is a cubic residue mod $p$, but $2$ and $3$ are not cubic residues mod $p$? If there are, can we give a expression of $p$?

Comment: nobody knows anything about your question (2). I can probably work out your question (1) in terms of binary quadratic forms.

Comment: read results of Gauss and Jacobi on page 134 http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hudson_Williams_1991.pdf

Comment: For (2) the answer is surely yes --- the first few such primes occur for k=0,-2,3,-4,4,5,-6,-9,10,11 --- but (as with every other case of Bunyakowsky's conjecture in degree 2 or greater) no technique is known that could prove it.  Fortunately this is not needed for a positive answer to (1), which will follow by applying Chebotarev's density theorem to a suitable extension of the third cyclotomic field.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I get $  p = 7 x^2 + 6 xy + 36 y^2 $

Comment: @ Will Jagy , @Noam D.Elkies Are there infinite such primes?(This question is asked by me, and I am sorry I have missed a requirement: $gcd(\frac{p-1}{6},6)=1$). Since $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, we have $p=\pi\bar{\pi}$, where $\pi$ is a primitive prime in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ and $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$. Assume $\pi=3m-1+3n\omega$, where $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$. I have worked out that $p$ satisfies all the requirements (except $gcd(\frac{p-1}{6},6)=1$), if and only if 1) $m$ is odd, n is odd, $n\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ or 2)$m$ is even, n is odd, $n\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ (continued)

Comment: I just don't know whether or not there are infinite primes $p$ satisfying all the requirements (including $gcd(\frac{p-1}{6},6)=1$).

$p=1296k^2+36k+7$ is a example of 1), and I have found many primes $p=1296k^2+36k+7$ , but I don't know if there are infinite primes like this.

Comment: Please, Zuo, look up *Bunyakowsky's Conjecture*. You will find there is *no* one-variable quadratic for which it has been proved that the quadratic takes on infinitely many prime values.

Comment: Doesn't a positive answer for (1) follow immediately from the Cebotarev density theorem?

Comment: Posted to m.se, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3163220/are-there-infinitely-many-prime-p-satistying-the-following-conditions

Comment: After the latest edit, the body of the question doesn't match the title. And it's still not clear whether you have looked up Buyakowsky yet.

Answer (score 1):

You want primes
$$  p = 7 x^2 + 6 xy + 36 y^2 $$
with integers $x,y.$ Notice that such primes are represented by $4 s^2 + 2 st + 7 t^2$ and $7 u^2 + 3 uv + 9 v^2,$ so both $2$ and $3$ are not cubic residues. Here one could just write $s = 3y, t = x,$ for the other $u=x, v = 2y.$

Meanwhile, in $  p = 7 x^2 + 6 xy + 36 y^2 $ we could take $x=1$ and $y = 6k$ to arrive at your $7 + 36 k + 1296 k^2$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./primego
Input three coefficients a b c for positive f(x,y)= a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 
7 6 36
Discriminant  -972

Modulus for arithmetic progressions? 
3
Maximum number represented? 
3000

      7,     37,    139,    163,    181,    241,    313,    337,    349,    379,
    409,    421,    541,    571,    607,    631,    751,    859,    877,    937,
   1033,   1087,   1123,   1171,   1291,   1297,   1447,   1453,   1483,   1693,
   1741,   1747,   2011,   2161,   2239,   2311,   2371,   2473,   2539,   2647,
   2677,   2707,   2719,   2857,
```